# Change wifi SDIK and password on Windows

Tags: wifi, windows

I have a model A+ already configures and connected to my wifi. It is running some scripts using the internet connection. The scripts are running on boot, so there is no need of an interface to use it.

Now, I need to send the Pi to my brother and he has zero Pi knowledge and no HDMI monitor. The problem is that the Pi is not connecting to his wifi network and the A+ has no ethernet either.

Is there a way to change the SSID and password to match his network, but without using the Pi? Ie: could my brother modify the SSID and password on the bootable SD card just by using his Windows or Mac computer?

Then he should be able to run the Pi just by inserting the SD card back into it and powering it. The script will be then running on boot.

Comment: Does he have a TV he can plug it into, or a DVI monitor that he can get an adapter for?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not just meddle with the SD card as far as I know.

Tricky fixes I can come up with (not "clean")

**A:**

You could try and SSH into the Pi in your network, change the scripts and save them, send it back to your brother.

**B:**

Change the SSID/PW of your brother's wifi temporarily to get into the pi over SSH and change the scripts.

Use Putty as an SSH client for a Windows machine.

*note: you can check the router to see if the Pi is connected or not.*

Comment: You *can* put the SD card in another computer and edit it, just you would need some added software on Windows or OSX to read the `ext4` filesystem.  Alternately, you could use linux in a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) on either OS.